# how to get instagram feed on home page using instagram gem - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instagram-api

I am using the instagram gem and have been trying to get an instagram feed on my sites home page but after getting all of my code in I am getting this error:

```
Instagram::BadRequest in PageController#home
this user does not exist
```

I am pretty sure I have the correct keys and user id. I suspect it has something to so with the code in my controller but I cant figure out what it could be.

Here are the steps that I have done so far:

I registered my client and received the client id and then used went through the steps to get the access key. I have created an initializer file where I put the client id and access token:

config/initializers/instagram.rb:

```
     require "instagram"
        Instagram.configure do |config|
        config.client_id = 'xxxx'
        config.access_token = 'xxxx'  
     end
```

I have put the user id in the controller

page_controller:

```
  def home
     @instagram = Instagram.user_recent_media("3021131281")
  end
```

home.html.erb:

```
<div>
    <% @instagram.each do |instagram| %>
      <%= image_tag instagram.images.first.last.url %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The user id 3021131281 is [a valid user](https://apigee.com/embed/console/instagram?req=%7B%22resource%22%3A%22get_users%22%2C%22params%22%3A%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22template%22%3A%7B%22user-id%22%3A%223021131281%22%7D%2C%22headers%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22body%22%3A%7B%22attachmentFormat%22%3A%22mime%22%2C%22attachmentContentDisposition%22%3A%22form-data%22%7D%7D%2C%22verb%22%3A%22get%22%7D).